# Test if login is an scp connection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I'm echo'ing various machine statistics on login, but this is problematic for SCP and SFTP, is there a shell variable I can test for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash, I use `shopt -q login_shell` to test for that.  For example in .bashrc:

```
if shopt -q login_shell
then
    echo "interesting stuff"
fi
```

This should keep the "interesting stuff" out of your scp/sftp.

Answer (score 5):

According to the man page, you should test for the presence of "i" in `$-`.

> PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive,  allowing
>          a shell script or a startup file to test this state.

For example:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    # do interactive stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Historically, in cleanly configured bourne-style shells, it's "test if PS1 is set", but that's broken if some joker exports PS1 to the environment.

The SUS standards-compliant method is to test if 'i' is in $-, as Dennis notes, although [[ ... ]] is non-standard, as is the == comparator.  So the most portable standards-compliant check is:

```
case $- in
 *i*) # do interactive stuff
  ;;
esac
```

Then you have `shopt -q login_shell` for bash (per Cakemox), and both `[[ -o interactive ]]` and `[[ -o login ]]` for zsh.